# Grails auto-compile on edit

Tags: macos, grails, terminal

I have been writing grails applications on Windows, and when I am editing the .groovy files and save they are automatically compiled while the application is running and the changes are available without restarting the app. On OSX this is not happening, in neither interactive mode or by starting the application with grails run-app.

Looking up online I couldn't find a reason for this, and also I know other people working on OSX where this feature works.

Any suggestions as to what might cause this?

Grails 2.3.7
OSX 10.9.4
Java 1.7.0_55

Answer (score 0):

If you are not running in forked mode, you will need to specify the `-reloading` explicitly.

Starting at some point, the initial JVM has reloading disabled and forks a new JVM with options specified in the `grails.project.fork = [...]` in `BuildConfig.groovy`.

As an alternative to passing `-reloading` each time, you can also modify the `startGrails` script included with the distribution and change the following option to false:

`DISABLE_RELOADING=false`

For me, the startGrails script is found in the GVM directory at `~/.gvm/grails/2.3.11/bin/startGrails`.

Comment: The same project is run on windows and OSX, and windows compile works as expected.

Comment: Windows and OSX will use different startup scripts, i.e. Windows uses startGrails.bat and OSX uses just startGrails. Perhaps something different about the startup parameters.